# would like to print the properties of objects in environment in R

Tags: r, object, environment

This sort of works but i wondered if there was a more elegant way?

```
unlist(lapply(lapply(ls(), get), class))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mget` which is multiple `get` and then use `sapply` to get `class` to avoid `unlist(lapply(...`

```
sapply(mget(ls()), class)
```

Answer (score 1):

With `purrr`, we can do

```
library(purrr)
mget(ls()) %>%
      map_chr(class)
```